# Monitor cookie creation

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I am investigating where a cookie is being set but I am not be able to find where. I cannot see it in HTTP headers so I suppose it is being created via Javascript. Is there any way to monitor where/when a cookie is set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install The [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension to [Firefox](http://www.getfirefox.net/), then install the [Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/) plugin ([Firecookie blog entry](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firecookie/)). FireCookie adds a panel to Firebug to show you cookie activity.

When looking at the list of cookies, if you right click on one and check `Break on '[cookie name]' change`, then whenever the cookie changes (if it is a change initiated by a script) Firebug will halt execution of the page and switch panels to the Script panel with the script/line which made the change highlighted for you. If it doesn't ever break, even though you see the cookie change, then the cookie was not modified by a script.

Comment: Yes, I have got it yet but I can only see which cookies are creates and its values

Comment: Update: Firecookie is now integrated in Firebug and can *not* be installed separately for Firebug to function.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't see them it in HTTP headers, you need to look for `document.cookie` in the JavaScript files included in the page.

A cookie is set by assigning a new value to `document.cookie`.

```
document.cookie = 'name=value;domain=.example.com;path=/;expires=...';
```

Comment: I know but I an not be able to find where it is created. Is there any way to debug page load to monitor cookies creation?